# How to Hide div tag for mobile devices only?

Tags: css

I want to hide "Advertisement" div tag for Mobile device only. So Help me How to hide for Mobile devices only.

Image where Div tag appeared - https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwZLa.jpg

Here is code which i am applied directly in Wordpress widget.

`
/*----------Sponsor Label Code for All----------*/

```
 .Ad-label{
        color: #444;
        background: #00FFFFFF;
        font-family: arial;
        padding: 3px 10px;
        font-size: 0px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);      -webkit-transform-origin: left top;      -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);      -moz-transform-origin: left top;      -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);      -ms-transform-origin: left top;      -o-transform: rotate(90deg);      -o-transform-origin: left top;      transform: rotate(90deg);      transform-origin: left top;        
        position: absolute;            
        left: 1%;      
        top:0px;
        white-space: nowrap;          
        font-size: 11px;
        display: inline-block;}
```

AdvertisementAdsense Code Goes Here`

Comment: Let you know? Have you searched before asking?

Comment: Yes searched and try a lot.

Comment: But look at it, I've momentarily found a solution. Have no idea how you searched :)

Comment: Hi, But old thread method is not working in my case. Now ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use css media query

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.Ad-label { display: none; }
}
```

Comment: Can u put ur code in fiddle